# federated learning implementing

Tags: python, machine-learning, federated-learning

I new in python and machine learning. I tried to implement the following code for federated learning with the MNIST dataset but it doesn't work !! it tried to train a model in a distributed way in local workers. the jpeg version of the MNIST data set is using here. It consists of 42000 digit images with each class kept in a separate folder. I will load the data into memory using this code snippet and keep 10% of the data for testing the trained global model later on.
**The following error appears when i implement the following fl_implemetation.py**

```
(base) C:\python1>fl_implemetation.py

  File "C:\python1\fl_implemetation.py", line 112
    global_acc, global_loss = test_model(X_test, Y_test, global_model, comm_round)SGD_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_train, y_train)).shuffle(len(y_train)).batch(320)
                                                                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
 there are two python files, first **fl_implemetation.py**.
```

The original code I am using can be found here: 
https://github.com/datafrick/tutorial

```
import NumPy as np
import random
import cv2
import os
from imutils import paths
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

import TensorFlow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D
from tensorflow.keras.layers import MaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Activation
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import SGD
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K

from fl_mnist_implementation_tutorial_utils import *

#declear path to your mnist data folder
img_path = '/path/to/your/training/dataset'

#get the path list using the path object
image_paths = list(paths.list_images(img_path))

#apply our function
image_list, label_list = load(image_paths, verbose=10000)

#binarize the labels
lb = LabelBinarizer()
label_list = lb.fit_transform(label_list)

#split data into training and test set
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(image_list, 
                                                    label_list, 
                                                    test_size=0.1, 
                                                    random_state=42)

#create clients
clients = create_clients(X_train, y_train, num_clients=10, initial='client')

#process and batch the training data for each client
clients_batched = dict()
for (client_name, data) in clients.items():
    clients_batched[client_name] = batch_data(data)

#process and batch the test set  
test_batched = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_test, y_test)).batch(len(y_test))

comms_round = 100

#create optimizer
lr = 0.01 
loss='categorical_crossentropy'
metrics = ['accuracy']
optimizer = SGD(lr=lr, 
                decay=lr / comms_round, 
                momentum=0.9
               ) 

#initialize global model
smlp_global = SimpleMLP()
global_model = smlp_global.build(784, 10)

#commence global training loop
for comm_round in range(comms_round):

    # get the global model's weights - will serve as the initial weights for all local models
    global_weights = global_model.get_weights()

    #initial list to collect local model weights after scalling
    scaled_local_weight_list = list()

    #randomize client data - using keys
    client_names= list(clients_batched.keys())
    random.shuffle(client_names)

    #loop through each client and create new local model
    for client in client_names:
        smlp_local = SimpleMLP()
        local_model = smlp_local.build(784, 10)
        local_model.compile(loss=loss, 
                      optimizer=optimizer, 
                      metrics=metrics)

        #set local model weight to the weight of the global model
        local_model.set_weights(global_weights)

        #fit local model with client's data
        local_model.fit(clients_batched[client], epochs=1, verbose=0)

        #scale the model weights and add to list
        scaling_factor = weight_scalling_factor(clients_batched, client)
        scaled_weights = scale_model_weights(local_model.get_weights(), scaling_factor)
        scaled_local_weight_list.append(scaled_weights)

        #clear session to free memory after each communication round
        K.clear_session()

    #to get the average over all the local model, we simply take the sum of the scaled weights
    average_weights = sum_scaled_weights(scaled_local_weight_list)

    #update global model 
    global_model.set_weights(average_weights)

    #test global model and print out metrics after each communications round
    for(X_test, Y_test) in test_batched:
        global_acc, global_loss = test_model(X_test, Y_test, global_model, comm_round)SGD_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_train, y_train)).shuffle(len(y_train)).batch(320)
smlp_SGD = SimpleMLP()
SGD_model = smlp_SGD.build(784, 10) 

SGD_model.compile(loss=loss, 
              optimizer=optimizer, 
              metrics=metrics)

# fit the SGD training data to model
_ = SGD_model.fit(SGD_dataset, epochs=100, verbose=0)

#test the SGD global model and print out metrics
for(X_test, Y_test) in test_batched:
        SGD_acc, SGD_loss = test_model(X_test, Y_test, SGD_model, 1)
```

and second **fl_mnist_implementation_tutorial_utils.py**

```
import NumPy as np
import random
import cv2
import os
from imutils import paths
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

import TensorFlow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D
from tensorflow.keras.layers import MaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Activation
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import SGD
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K

def load(paths, verbose=-1):
    '''expects images for each class in separate dir, 
    e.g all digits in 0 class in the directory named 0 '''
    data = list()
    labels = list()
    # loop over the input images
    for (i, imgpath) in enumerate(paths):
        # load the image and extract the class labels
        im_gray = cv2.imread(imgpath, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
        image = np.array(im_gray).flatten()
        label = imgpath.split(os.path.sep)[-2]
        # scale the image to [0, 1] and add to list
        data.append(image/255)
        labels.append(label)
        # show an update every `verbose` images
        if verbose > 0 and i > 0 and (i + 1) % verbose == 0:
            print("[INFO] processed {}/{}".format(i + 1, len(paths)))
    # return a tuple of the data and labels
    return data, labels


def create_clients(image_list, label_list, num_clients=10, initial='clients'):
    ''' return: a dictionary with keys clients' names and value as 
                data shards - tuple of images and label lists.
        args: 
            image_list: a list of numpy arrays of training images
            label_list:a list of binarized labels for each image
            num_client: number of fedrated members (clients)
            initials: the clients'name prefix, e.g, clients_1 

    '''

    #create a list of client names
    client_names = ['{}_{}'.format(initial, i+1) for i in range(num_clients)]

    #randomize the data
    data = list(zip(image_list, label_list))
    random.shuffle(data)

    #shard data and place at each client
    size = len(data)//num_clients
    shards = [data[i:i + size] for i in range(0, size*num_clients, size)]

    #number of clients must equal number of shards
    assert(len(shards) == len(client_names))

    return {client_names[i] : shards[i] for i in range(len(client_names))}



def batch_data(data_shard, bs=32):
    '''Takes in a clients data shard and create a tfds object off it
    args:
        shard: a data, label constituting a client's data shard
        bs:batch size
    return:
        tfds object'''
    #seperate shard into data and labels lists
    data, label = zip(*data_shard)
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((list(data), list(label)))
    return dataset.shuffle(len(label)).batch(bs)


class SimpleMLP:
    @staticmethod
    def build(shape, classes):
        model = Sequential()
        model.add(Dense(200, input_shape=(shape,)))
        model.add(Activation("relu"))
        model.add(Dense(200))
        model.add(Activation("relu"))
        model.add(Dense(classes))
        model.add(Activation("softmax"))
        return model


def weight_scalling_factor(clients_trn_data, client_name):
    client_names = list(clients_trn_data.keys())
    #get the bs
    bs = list(clients_trn_data[client_name])[0][0].shape[0]
    #first calculate the total training data points across clinets
    global_count = sum([tf.data.experimental.cardinality(clients_trn_data[client_name]).numpy() for client_name in client_names])*bs
    # get the total number of data points held by a client
    local_count = tf.data.experimental.cardinality(clients_trn_data[client_name]).numpy()*bs
    return local_count/global_count


def scale_model_weights(weight, scalar):
    '''function for scaling a models weights'''
    weight_final = []
    steps = len(weight)
    for i in range(steps):
        weight_final.append(scalar * weight[i])
    return weight_final



def sum_scaled_weights(scaled_weight_list):
    '''Return the sum of the listed scaled weights. The is equivalent to scaled avg of the weights'''
    avg_grad = list()
    #get the average grad accross all client gradients
    for grad_list_tuple in zip(*scaled_weight_list):
        layer_mean = tf.math.reduce_sum(grad_list_tuple, axis=0)
        avg_grad.append(layer_mean)

    return avg_grad


def test_model(X_test, Y_test,  model, comm_round):
    cce = tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
    #logits = model.predict(X_test, batch_size=100)
    logits = model.predict(X_test)
    loss = cce(Y_test, logits)
    acc = accuracy_score(tf.argmax(logits, axis=1), tf.argmax(Y_test, axis=1))
    print('comm_round: {} | global_acc: {:.3%} | global_loss: {}'.format(comm_round, acc, loss))
    return acc, loss
```

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not a question. Post the error that you receive when trying to run your code, please.

Comment: (base) C:\python1>fl_implemetation.py
  File "C:\python1\fl_implemetation.py", line 112
    global_acc, global_loss = test_model(X_test, Y_test, global_model, comm_round)SGD_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_train, y_train)).shuffle(len(y_train)).batch(320)
                                                                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add `\n` in this line:

```
global_acc, global_loss = test_model(X_test, Y_test, global_model, comm_round)SGD_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_train, y_train)).shuffle(len(y_train)).batch(320)
```

So, this line should be two lines like so:

```
global_acc, global_loss = test_model(X_test, Y_test, global_model, comm_round)

SGD_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_train, y_train)).shuffle(len(y_train)).batch(320)
```

Comment: thank you Anwarvic, but i still have errors with                                      
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2' , ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'imutils', ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn'

Comment: Then, you need to install them: run these commands `pip install cv2`, `pip install imutils` and `pip install sklearn`.